# Proving the convexity of frobenius norm and correlation function in a multi-output regression setting

Tags: convex-optimization, regression, non-convex-optimization

I have been working on formulating my requirements in the form of an optimization problem in a multi-output regression setting.
Firstly, I would like to make the variables I used in the problem and their dimensions clear.

There are $Q$ outputs, $N$ samples, and $P$ covariates (features).

$\hat{Y}\in\mathbb R^{Q\times N}$ is the prediction matrix,

$$\hat{Y}=WX$$

where $W\in\mathbb R^{Q\times P}$ is the parameter matrix. These are the parameters we estimate in the regression.

$X\in\mathbb R^{P\times N}$ is the data matrix

My requirement:

I want to preserve the correlation structure in multi-output regression, i.e., the correlation structure of the predictions and the correlation structure of the data should remain close. I had two formulations for it.
I am assuming that the $Y$'s are standardized, Hence $YY^{T}$ is equal to the correlation matrix of the data.

**Formulation 1**: Minimize the Frobenius norm of the difference between the correlation matrices of the data and the predictions

$$W^{*}=\underset{w}{\mathrm{argmin}}\frac{1}{\mathcal{N}}\|YY^{T}-\hat{Y}\hat{Y}^{T}\|_{F}^{2}$$

**Formulation 2**: Maximize the correlation between the correlation matrices of the data and the predictions

$$W^{*}=\underset{w}{\mathrm{argmax}} \operatorname{cor}\left(Y{Y}^{T}, \hat{Y}\hat{Y}^{T}\right)$$

where $\operatorname{cor}$ is the correlation function.

Now I have to prove the convexity of the above formulations:

My attempts: (I am giving a very brief description of what I have done and I can elaborate if it helps, kindly ask in the comments section)

I didn't try to generalize the proof for matrices of any size. I started with a matrix $W$ of very small dimensions ($2\times 1$) and $X$ of dimension($1\times 2$) and then tried to prove that the Hessian matrix for both above formulations is PSD (positive semi-definite). The result tends to depend on the values of the matrix $X$ and $Y$.

I am stuck with generalizing this proof. Kindly give your valuable suggestions to prove the convexity/nonconvexity of both the above formulations.

**UPDATE**: In Formulation 2 I was wondering if I could use the positive semi definiteness properties of the matrices $YY$$^{T}$,$XX$$^{T}$ so I tried the following:

Note: i am replacing the feature correlation matrix $XX$$^{T}$ with $B$ and the output correlation matrix  $YY$$^{T}$ with $C$
\begin{align}
W=\begin{bmatrix}
 \alpha_{11}&\alpha_{12}\\
 \alpha_{21}&\alpha_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
B=\begin{bmatrix}
 b_{11}&b_{12}\\
 b_{21}&b_{22}\\
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
C=\begin{bmatrix}
 c_{11}&c_{12}\\
 c_{21}&c_{22}\\
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$\hat{Y}\hat{Y}^{T}=WXX^{T}W^{T}=WBW^{T}$

now i am rewriting $\operatorname{cor}\left(Y{Y}^{T}, \hat{Y}\hat{Y}^{T}\right)$ as $Vec(C)\cdot\!Vec(WBW^{T})$

now this is my new loss function :
$L(\alpha)=Vec(C)\cdot\!Vec(WBW^{T})$.(as $W$ is a function of $\alpha$).

I have calculated the Hessian of the above loss function $L(\alpha)$ for dimensions of $W$($2\times2$),$C$($2\times2$),$B$($2\times2$) and ultimately the Hessian turns out to be $2*C\otimes B$ .Where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product between two matrices. As both $B$ and $C$ are PSD matrices the Kronecker product of them should also be a PSD matrix (please find the link to the proof below) which means my loss function $L(\alpha)$ should be convex. But however, this may not hold for larger examples as I didn't generalize the proof.

[Look at Corollary 2.4 for proof](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/reports/kronthesisschaecke04.pdf)

Comment: your first formulation is, up to rescaling, Eckhart Young.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525372/prove-eckart-young-minsky-theorem-for-frobinius-norm/3526152#3526152  I didn't follow what you are doing with the second formulation.  The title of this posting is "proving the convexity of frobenius norm..."  That is done by applying $p\big \Vert X \big \Vert_F  = \big \Vert pX \big \Vert_F $ for $p \in [0,1]$ (in general: homogeneity of scaling by non-negative numbers) and subadditivity (i.e. triangle inequality).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3535732/14578, https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/34365/4274, https://mathoverflow.net/q/352205/37212.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).