# Low-rank approximation and Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem for complex matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

For the classic problem of low-rank approximation:

> \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
> \min_{r(F) \leq k} \lVert X - F \rVert_F 
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation}

for a given constant real matrix $X$ approximated by $ F $ of rank at most $ k $. I know the Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem states the solution when $ X $ is real but what about when $ X $ is a matrix with complex entries? Is the solution using SVD still the same as the Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem? I am referring here to the Frobenius matrix norm which is well-defined for complex matrices as well and always positive. I wonder if Eckart-Young-Mirsky carries over to complex numbers for the Frobenius norm. I thank all helpers for any references to solutions for the complex problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prove Eckart-Young-Minsky theorem for Frobinius norm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525372/prove-eckart-young-minsky-theorem-for-frobinius-norm)

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate.  If you look at my proof above then you'll see I proved it over $\mathbb C$ about 2 months ago.  It really is an easy result if you know the von-Neumann trace inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes: the result holds (with the same formula) if we discuss complex matrices under the Frobenius norm. As for a reference, note that the paper of Mirsky (the third name in the theorem) is about complex matrices.  The citation:

> The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics, Volume 11, Issue 1, 1960, Pages 50–59, https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/11.1.50