# The matrix which minimize Frobenius norm is unique? or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Here, matrices $P,Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ are satisfied with ${\rm rank}(Q)=r$, ${\rm rank}(P)\geq r$. I approximate $P$ as $Q$ in terms of Frobenius norm.

$$
Q' = \underset{Q \, : \,\operatorname{rank}(Q)=r}{\operatorname{arg min}} \| P - Q \|_F
$$

My question is below: is $Q'$ unique to given matrix $P$ ?

**Supplement**

I know Eckart-Young Theorem. According to this theorem,
$$
|| P - Q' ||_F = \sqrt{\sigma_{r+1}^2 + \cdots +  \sigma_{n}^2 }.
$$

$\sigma_i$ is $i$-th biggest singular value of $P$. We can get $Q'$ by singular values decomposition of $P$. When we find $r$ rank matrix $Q$ which is satisifed with $|| P - Q ||_F = \sqrt{\sigma_{r+1}^2 + \cdots +  \sigma_{n}^2 } $, is $Q$ same as the matrix which is given by $r$ rank approximation by singular values decomposition?

**EDIT**

Now, I understand $Q'$ is not unique to $P$.

When we find $r$ rank matrix $Q$ which is satisifed with $|| P - Q ||_F = \sqrt{\sigma_{r+1}^2 + \cdots +  \sigma_{n}^2 } $, how can I find $Q$ is same matrix as $r$-rank approximation of $P$ by SVD or not?

Comment: suppose $P = I_n$, and we want a rank $r=n-1$ approximation, is $Q'$ unique? Well I count $n$ different possibilities so it isn't unique.

Comment: @user8675309, I guess you want to say that the answers are $I_{n}$, where one $1$ is replaced with $0$. Is this really true? Can you show that they are minimizers?

Comment: @Dmitry -- yes that is correct.  In fact in the above case I can lower bound $\Big\Vert Q'-I\Big\Vert_F^2$ by the smallest squared singular value of $I$ that is we *know* $\Big\Vert Q'-I\Big\Vert_F^2 \geq 1$ and by inspection $Q':= I_n - \mathbf e_k\mathbf e_k^T$ with kth standard basis vector $\mathbf e_k$ for $k \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ meets the lower bound with equality, hence any choice of $k$ is a minimizer.  Naturally I think of this in terms of how I'd prove the bound, here:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525372/prove-eckart-young-minsky-theorem-for-frobinius-norm/3526152

Comment: @user8675309, I see, thanks!

Comment: @Sakurai There is a unique minimizer if and only if $\sigma_r \neq \sigma_{r+1}$.

Comment: @Sakurai.JJ The answer below gives one such proof.

Comment: @Sakurai.JJ Does the proof given make sense, or are you interested in an alternative approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\pi$ be an orthogonal projection of rank $r$ that commutes with $P^{\mathrm t}\!P$ then $Q = P \pi$ is a critical point of the function $$A \mapsto \lVert P - A \rVert^2$$ over all $A$ of rank $r$. Moreover $$\lVert P - Q \rVert^2 = \operatorname{tr}(P^{\mathrm t}\! P\cdot (1-\pi))$$ and this is minimal when $\pi$ projects to the eigenspaces of $P^{\mathrm t}\! P$ with highest eigenvalues (so $1-\pi$ projects to the eigenspaces with lowest eigenvalues).

Uniqueness of $\pi$ depends on the eigenspace decomposition of $P^{\mathrm t}\! P$ and in particular the multiplicities of its eigenvalues. For example, if the largest $r$ eigenvalues (counting multiplicity) are all distinct then $\pi$ is unique.  On the other extreme, when $P=1$ then all rank $r$ projections give the minimal distance.

Comment: Thank you. Is $||A||$ Spectral norm or Frobenius norm?

Comment: The Frobenius norm.